# Dumb question: how to replace or strip single quote in python for following situation

Tags: python

I know this is dumb question but still asking

I have a file which says- **' There is abundant evidence's.'**

Now I want to strip or replace ' to change it to- **There is abundant evidence's**

but when I use

```
  line = line.replace(" ' ", " ")
```

it is stripping all  **single quotes**. Is there any way not to replace single quote from **evidence's** ?

Don't assume this the only line in file.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import string

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line .lower()
    for char in '-",".:;[]()_\t\n?|!@#$%^&*+=/1234567890§':
        line=line.replace(char,' ')
        line = line.replace("'","")
        print line

    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        print('%s\t%s'%(word,1))
```

Comment: `line = line[1:-1]`, assuming that the single quote is both the first and last char. Otherwise, you need a more sophisticated parser which can decide what exceptions to use.

Comment: but this line can be present anywhere in the file

Comment: if you want to strip the single quotes surrounding a string, you can use `line.strip("'")`. but if the line doesn't start or end with the quote this won't work

Comment: @RonitSharma you can iterate over lines in the file (split the file into lines)

Comment: @RonitSharma As you can see, you cannot format code correctly in a comment. Instead, you should [edit] your original question to include the information.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah I have edited my question with code

Comment: I think you should first clearly define the rules that determine which `'` characters you want to remove and which you want to leave. You should attempt to describe these requirements in words before writing any code.

Comment: Your edit invalidated all the existing answers. Don't do thatt! I rolled the edit back.

Answer (score 2):

`strip()` will only remove outer `'`'s

```
s = "'There is abundant evidence's.'"
print(s.strip("'"))
# There is abundant evidence's.
```

Comment: output is-  There is abundant evidence's.' only stripping first single quote

Comment: @RonitSharma I'm getting proper output, can I see the exact way you are applying this ?

Comment: @RonitSharma I want to say its where you are nesting it at make sure its being applied to the entire string not just the word, and worst case you can use `r.strip("'")`

Comment: I have edited the question with the code if you want to look at it again.

Comment: Think like that- There is 'abundant' evidence's. Now how can i remove cause strip won't work in this case

Comment: @RonitSharma Okay going to look, got some things to catch up on, didn't forget tho

Answer (score 0):

Is this too specific?

```
print("' There is abundant evidence's.'".strip("'").strip(". "))
```

Comment: yes it is. As I said there are many lines like that for eg, ' course name' , ' don't throw' etc. and it is single quote not double quote.

Comment: Umm, but double strip calls works for both cases you mentioned in the comment. It removes only outer `'`.